# Gutenberg: where to find <main> style settings

Tags: css, block-editor, theme.json

I'm using the the Twenty-Twenty-Three theme, and having difficulty pinpointing a preset which has been applied directly to the style attribute of the  container of a page template.

I could not locate it in theme.json or the theme editor/page settings.

Any tips on finding where this is controlled would be great!

[image]